# jquery removes number from URL path with GET method

Tags: jquery, url, get

I use jquery to get a url content.

When the url contains a number, this number is removed by jquery and I get a 404. This happens randomly.

The use case is :

```
let ajax_otions = {
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/api/group/7/users",
    accepts: 'application/json',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token')
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: async
};

$.ajax(ajax_options)
.done(function(data) {
    console.log("AJAX GET successful");
})
.fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("AJAX GET failed");                    <= Get a 404 randomly
})
```

Chrome shows the number 7 has been removed.

Any clue about the reason ?

I've tried using encodeURIComponent(url) but it just does not run any more with this change.

The weird thing is that it runs properly most of the time. But from time to time, I get a 404 and when I look at the debugger in Chrome, I can see that the number has been removed from the url.

Comment: Just wondering about this line `async: async` is `async` a variable? If not, this expects `true` or `false`.

Comment: async is a var set to true by default.

Comment: Do you see any other alerts in Console or in Network?

Comment: There's nothing in jQuery that's going to modify that `url` property. If that `url` is not truly constant, then I'd be looking at how that `7` gets populated.

Comment: I'am logging the url value before the ajax call. I just added the same logging after the ajax call.

Comment: I've set async to false and then realized that I'am probably doing 2 times the ajax call. One time with the number and a second time without the number. In Chrome, the asynchronous behavior makes it looks like as if I had only done 1 ajax call with the number.

Answer (score 0):

Thx all for your help.

I'am doing the ajax call 2 times.

With async mode set to true, it looks like as if I do it only once with the correct url including the number.

But I did 2 ajax calls, one with the correct url and one with the url having the number removed.

In Chrome, it looks like just one single ajax call.

Just a matter of sequencing...